# X server problem on slackware 14 and poulsbo module (gma500)

Tags: linux, xorg, slackware

I have installed slackware 14 on my acer aspire one za3. I cannot start the X server. Here the output of command `startx`

```
xauth:  file /home/emanuele/.serverauth.1984 does not exist
X.Org X Server 1.12.3
Release Date: 2012-07-09
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Slackware 14.0 Slackware Linux Project
Current Operating System: Linux darkstar 3.2.29-smp #2 SMP Mon Sep 17 13:16:43 CDT 2012 i686
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=Linux ro root=803 vt.default_utf8=0
Build Date: 23 August 2012  02:27:55PM

Current version of pixman: 0.26.2
Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
(++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
(WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed Oct  3 18:46:58 2012
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
vesa: Ignoring device with a bound kernel driver

Fatal server error:
no screens found

Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
 at http://wiki.x.org
for help. 
Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.

Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.
xinit: giving up
xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused
xinit: server error
```

Seem to me that the psb module is loaded.
Here the output of `lsmod|grep psb`

```
psb_gfx               180538  0 
drm_kms_helper         22825  1 psb_gfx
drm                   151850  2 drm_kms_helper,psb_gfx
i2c_algo_bit            4543  1 psb_gfx
i2c_core               16454  6 i2c_algo_bit,i2c_isch,drm,drm_kms_helper,videodev,psb_gfx
video                   9938  2 poulsbo,psb_gfx
```

And this is the output `lspci` of my vga card

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation System Controller Hub (SCH Poulsbo) Graphics Controller [8086:8108] (rev 07) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] Device [1025:0244]
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
Memory at b0080000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=512K]
I/O ports at 1800 [size=8]
Memory at c0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256M]
Memory at b0000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=256K]
Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
Capabilities: [d0] Power Management version 2
```

I don't understand why it does not work. Where is the problem?

**Edit:** after a `rmmod poulsbo psb_gfx`, X start (with vesa driver i suppose). May be a bug?

Answer (score -1):

You should hand-edit the "Screen" section in your `xorg.conf`